# PHP replace mcrypt_cbc with mcrypt_generic

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have functions in PHP (5.3) and I had to upgrade PHP to be able to use current SDKs. Now I get follwoing Error:

Deprecated: Function mcrypt_cbc() is deprecated

I looked into the new mcrypt_generic as http://php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-cbc.php tells me and I tried to convert it but I never get the same result as with the old functions. Can anyone help me with converting. It already took me a long time to create the first functions because I am not into that crypting things a lot and now I am having a hard time to get it right.

Thank you very much!!!

```
   function decode ($string)
{
    $skey = "testKey";
    $siv = "testSIV";

    $keyArray = utf8_encode($skey);
    $toEncryptArray = base64_decode($string);
    $iv = utf8_encode($siv);

    $dec = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $keyArray, $toEncryptArray, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);

    $dec = utf8_decode($dec);
    return $dec;
}

function encode($string)
{
    $skey = "testKey";
    $siv = "testSIV";

    $keyArray = utf8_encode($skey);
    $toEncryptArray = utf8_encode($string);
    $iv = utf8_encode($siv);

    $enc = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $keyArray, $toEncryptArray, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv);

    $enc = base64_encode($enc);
    return $enc;
}
```

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment and hint. That makes it even harder for me because I need to decrypt the encrypted string in C# and that makes it hard to implement, because I do not know the exact agorithm :(

Comment: `mcrypt` does not support PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, C# (as all implementations not written by Bozos) does support PKCS#7 padding and most automatically and transparently add and remove the padding.

Comment: Note that 3DES should not be used i new work, in it's place use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). Also the usual way to generate a random iv and prepend it to the encrypted data for use during decryption, it does not need to be secret, it does need to be random so the same message encrypted with the same key is not the same.

Comment: If the wrong key is used or the encrypted data is corrupted the result will most likely not be convertible to a UTF-8 string so `utf8_decode($dec);` will fail in some manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Thant sound all reasonable but quite hard for me to change because I am not that much into these things. Does anyone have an example where I can crypt a string in C# and decrypt it with php and other way around. I would also appreciate links that would help me because google does not give me the right answers, I might be searching wrong ;)

Comment: If you have control of both sides and can replace both look at RNCryptor [README.md](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/blob/master/README.md) and [implementations](https://github.com/RNCryptor) which support several languages and platforms. It handles all the details that are hard to get correct.

Comment: okay thank you, I will check that out!